# Selenium IDE Commands

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Under what conditions will I have to manually add Commands like Mouse-Over, press-Key and many more, as if I run Selenium id and perform actions, isn't Selenium itself supposed to record all these Actions?

Comment: Youtube !? Have you tried the selenium documentation.

Comment: There isn't really a good question here to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE recorder doesn't record some of these actions, others it tries to translate (press key being sent as type). There are also some other actions it struggles with (typeable jquery divs).

It's an open source product so feel free to contribute ideas or code: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium